# JSON.net access values of deserialized list containing multiple types, including objects

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have the following json:

```
var x = [
    [99,"abc","2dp",{"Group": 0,"Total":[4, 1]}],
    [7,"x","date"],
    [60,"x","1dp",{"Group": 1}],
    ...
]
```

I need to deserialize this json but I'm having trouble with the object in field 3. This was a first attempt:

```
string x = "[[99,\"abc\",\"2dp\",{\"Group\": 0,\"Total\":[4, 1]}],[7,\"x\",\"date\"],[60,\"x\",\"1dp\",{\"Group\": 1}]]";
List<List<object>> xobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>(x);
```

This appears to work. Using the intermediate window in Visual Studio 2015:

```
xobj[0][0];
99

xobj[1][2];
"date"
```

However I'm not sure how to access the object in field 3?

```
xobj[0][3];
{{
  "Group": 0,
  "Total": [
    4,
    1
  ]
}}
    ChildrenTokens: Count = 2
    Count: 2
    First: {"Group": 0}
    HasValues: true
    Last: {"Total": [
  4,
  1
]}
    Next: null
    Parent: null
    Path: ""
    Previous: null
    Root: {{
  "Group": 0,
  "Total": [
    4,
    1
  ]
}}
    Type: Object
    Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
    Dynamic View: Expanding the Dynamic View will get the dynamic members for the object

xobj[0][3].Root["Group"];
error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Root' and no extension method 'Root' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I noticed it had a 'First' method, so I tried this, but also no luck:

```
xobj[0][3][0];
error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
```

So how can I access values within the object of each list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanna access the optional entry then try this out:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = "[[99,\"abc\",\"2dp\",{\"Group\": 0,\"Total\":[4, 1]}],[7,\"x\",\"date\"],[60,\"x\",\"1dp\",{\"Group\": 1}]]";
        List<List<object>> xobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>(x);

        for (int i = 0; i < xobj.Count; i++)
        {
            // Do something with index 0 to 3
            if (xobj[i].Count == 4)
            {
                // I have the optional entry with Group & Total properties
                dynamic opt = xobj[i][3];
                Console.WriteLine("GROUP: " + opt.Group); // Mandatory
                Console.WriteLine("GROUP value: " + opt.Group.Value);

                if (opt["Total"] != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TOTAL: " + opt.Total);
                    Console.WriteLine("TOTAL item 0 value: " + opt.Total[0].Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("TOTAL item 1 value: " + opt.Total[1].Value);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: doing this just outputs a whole load of text, and not an `int` value like i wanted:{1}
    First: '((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)opt.Group).First' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    HasValues: false
    Last: '((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)opt.Group).Last' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    Next: null
    Parent: {"Group": 1}
    Path: "Group"
    Previous: null
    Root: {{
  "Group": 1

Comment: could you tell me how to get the value of Group though? Like how can I get `int groupVal = opt.Group...?`

Comment: ahh its with `opt.Group.Value`

Comment: The dynamic opt is actually of type [JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm). Look up its documentation for more info.

Comment: how would I get `Total` as a `List<int>`?

Comment: Ah ok. I will look up the documentation on JObject.

Comment: To make things simpler why not create a model class for your JSON? So you can just de-serialize your JSON string to an object?

Comment: I have done that actually. I will post another question since its not working currently

Comment: Try `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray list = opt["Total"]; int[] nlist = list.Select(ii => (int)ii).ToArray();` it worked for me converting JArray to int array.

Comment: Here is my failed attempt at deserializing into a model class - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348405/deserialize-json-into-custom-list