# Deserialize JSON into custom list

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, .net-4.5

I have this json:

```
var x = [
    [99,"abc","2dp",{"GroupNum": 0,"Total":[4, 1]}],
    [7,"x","date"],
    [60,"x","1dp",{"GroupNum": 1}],
    ...
]
```

The following rules exist (let `i` refer to the inner list index):

- `x[i][0]` - mandatory item - always an integer
- `x[i][1]` - mandatory item - always a string
- `x[i][2]` - mandatory item - always a string
- `x[i][3]` - optional item - when it exists then it has the following rules:

  - `x[i][3].GroupNum` - mandatory field - always an integer
  - `x[i][3].Total` - optional field - when it exists then it is a list of integers

So I have created the following classes for these rules:

```
public class ReportTemplateField : System.Collections.CollectionBase
{
    public object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0:
                    return (int)List[index];
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    return (string)List[index];
                case 3:
                    return (ReportGrouping)List[index];
                default:
                    throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Class ReportTemplateField only contains 4 items");
            }
        }
        set
        {
            switch (Count)
            {
                case 0:
                    List[index] = unchecked((int)value);
                    break;
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    List[index] = (string)value;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    List[index] = (ReportGrouping)value;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Class ReportTemplateField may only contain 4 items");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(object item)
    {
        switch (Count)
        {
            case 0:
                List.Add(unchecked((int)item));
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
                List.Add((string)item);
                break;
            case 3:
                List.Add((ReportGrouping)item);
                break;
            default:
                throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Class ReportTemplateField may only contain 4 items");
        }
    }
}

public class ReportGrouping
{
    public int GroupNum { get; set; }
    public List<int> Total { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I attempt to deserialize using json.net, the `ReportTemplateField` class never gets used. I know this because I have put breakpoints in every method and none of them get triggered:

```
string json = "[[99,\"abc\",\"2dp\",{\"GroupNum\": 0,\"Total\":[4, 1]}],[7,\"x\",\"date\"],[60,\"x\",\"1dp\",{\"GroupNum\": 1}]]";
List<ReportTemplateField> parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReportTemplateField>>(json);
int Total01 = parsed[0][3].Total[1];
```

gives me this error:

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Total' and
>   no extension method 'Total' accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

However it works if I just deserialize the `ReportGrouping` in isolation:

```
string json2 = "{\"GroupNum\": 0,\"Total\":[4, 1]}";
ReportGrouping parsed2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportGrouping>(json2);
parsed2.Total[1]; // 1
```

So the problem lies with the `ReportTemplateField` class. Maybe I shouldn't be inheriting from `System.Collections.CollectionBase`? I basically followed this walkthough with some modifications - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xth2y6ft(v=vs.71).aspx but it does say that the documentation may be outdated. I'm using .NET 4.5 so please factor that into any your answers.

How can I get Json.net to deserialize correctly, so that I can just go `parsed[0][3].Total[1];` to access the integer value of the second total without needing to cast it or do anything to it at all?

Comment: Is your `x` "Json" just pseudo-code? I'm being picky, but it's not a valid Json string

Comment: its javascript. but that's not really important to this question. just go by the `string json = ...` half way down - its the same. you can omit the `...` - that's just to imply there are more lists within the main list.

Comment: Cool, yeah I got the `...` bit - just wanted to check. If it's any help to you, I like to create C# classes from Json objects and parse them out that way. Try using: http://json2csharp.com If you post some actual raw Json in there you will get some neat C# classes out the other end. (partly the reason I asked about the Json, I was going to try and paste some in and see how it turned out). Then the JsonConvert class can parse them back and populate your C# classes. I suspect your error is to do with using the `System.Collections.CollectionBase` derivation

Comment: cool idea. but i can't get it to work with any json. even `[1,2,3]` fails

Comment: are you sure? jsonlint.com says its valid

Comment: Scratch that invalid Json comment. You would need to have the Json parsed with key/value pairs in order to convert it to C# classes. Where is your Json coming from? Is it your own, or from a 3rd party API?

Comment: i tried the following in json2csharp.com - `{"x":[
    [99,"abc","2dp",{"GroupNum": 0,"Total":[4, 1]}],
    [7,"x","date"],
    [60,"x","1dp",{"GroupNum": 1}]
]}` but it just gives `public class RootObject
{
    public List<List<object>> x { get; set; }
}`

Comment: Fair enough. Like I said, I wasn't able to try it out myself to see the result. Sorry I couldn't help any more. Best of luck in your project :)

Comment: no worries. it may come in useful some time :) thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a few errors in the code, 1 is that object does not have a property called Total and another is that parsed[0][3] is a string.

You have a few errors in the code:

1. parsed[0][3] is a string. Fix it by converting the string into a ReportGrouping.
2. new ReportGrouping().GroupName should be named Group according to Json.
3. After you have parsed parsed[0][3] into a ReportingGroup it will still return a object, so cast i into a ReportingGroup afterwards. I.e. (ReportingGroup)parsed[0][3].

   ```
   get
   {
       switch (index)
       {
           case 0:
               return (int)List[index];
           case 1:
           case 2:
               return (string)List[index];
           case 3:
               return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportGrouping>(List[index].ToString());
           default:
               throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Class ReportTemplateField only contains 4 items");
       }
   }
   ```

And use it like this:

```
List<ReportTemplateField> parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReportTemplateField>>(json);
ReportGrouping group = (ReportGrouping)parsed[0][3];
```

Dont forget to rename GroupName into Group and to fix the setter.

EDIT: Sorry for repeating myself so many times..

Comment: Thanks so much for looking at this! But why do you say that the object does not have a property called `Total`? `Total` exists in the `ReportGrouping` (at the bottom of the c# code sample). Also I will fix the json in the question as that is just a typo left over from a previous version of my code.

Comment: Also, any idea why the setter never gets called by json.net? I tried putting a breakpoint in the setter but it never gets triggered.

Comment: parsed[0][3] returns an item of the class type object(thats what specified on the getter). You then need to convert it to the class type ReportGrouping, which has the property Total. And you convert it by writing (ReportGrouping) before.

Comment: In the code example you never assign a value, hence you do not use the setter. An example: ReportTemplateField tmp = new ReportTemplateField();
            tmp[0] = 1;
            tmp[1] = "string";
            tmp[2] = "string2";
            tmp[3] = group; Also, you will notice a problem when using the setter, cause of errors in it as well..

Comment: Ah I see. Is there any way to cast it as `ReportGrouping` within the getter? Or even within the setter so it stores that item as type `ReportGrouping` internally? I thought about using `public T this[int index]` for the indexer, but I don't know if this would enable returning as the `ReportGrouping` type?

Comment: Also I don't understand why you say, "In the code example you never assign a value"? I thought `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` would assign a value. It does this in `parsed2` in my second test.

Comment: I do not think it is possible. Because you are also returning items of type int and string. But maybe with generics, but highly unlikely. If it was only 1 type it was returning all the time, then it would be possible.

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() does not use the setter.

Comment: hmm. i've had another idea - i can add properties to the `ReportTemplateField` class to store the various list items, then use a custom converter to deserialize the list into the class and to serialize the class back into a list. i think this is going to be the best approach. problem is i have no idea how to use json.net's custom converter function, and i can't find any examples which map items in a list into properties of a class. i will write another question here on stackoverflow after i have played around with it for a bit.